# How to select two single files from one function?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my HTML in which there are 2 input fields, I want to grab both the files from these input tags and do the further operations.

```
 <label for="idProof" class="uploadArea">
                            <input
                              ref="idProof"
                              type="file"
                              id="idProof"
                              accept="image/*"
                              @change="selectFile"
                              hidden
                            />

                          </label>
```

```
 <label for="addressProof" class="uploadArea">
                            <input
                              ref="addressProof"
                              type="file"
                              id="addressProof"
                              accept="image/*"
                              @change="selectFile"
                              hidden
                            />

                          </label>
```

I want to select files from both of these input tags in a `selectFiles()` function. So how should I write `selectFiles()` function.

Comment: If this is part of a javascript framework you should tag it appropriately with that framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you want something like the below,

```
<body>
<input type="file" onchange="selectFiles(this)"><br/>
<input type="file" onchange="selectFiles(this)">
<script>
let files=[];
function selectFiles(t){
files.push(t.value);
if(files.length===2){
alert(files); //or do some operation
}
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't want multiple images from a single input. I want two single images from 2 different input tags.